# Deleting comments in a large file

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to delete a bunch of comments that are all in the following format:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc

 ... comment body (delete me, too!)

*/
```

I have tried using this command: `%s/\/**\n * @ngdoc.\{-}*\///g`

Here is the regex without the patterns: `%s/pattern1.\{-}pattern2//g`

Here are the individual patterns: `\/**\n * @ngdoc` and `*\/`

When I try my pattern in vim I get the following error:

```
E871: (NFA regexp) Can't have a multi follow a multi !
E61: Nested *
E476: Invalid command
```

Thanks for any help with this regexp nightmare!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to cram this into one complex regex, it's much easier to search for the start of a comment and delete from there on to the end of a comment

```
:g/^\/\*\*$/,/\*\/$/d_
```

This breaks down into

```
:g               start a global command
/^\/\*\*$/       search for start of a comment: <sol>/**<eol>
,/^\*\/$/        extend the range to the end of a comment: <sol>*/<eol>
d                delete the range
_                use the black hole register (performance optimization)
```

Comment: Using very magic is unnecessary once all slashes and asteriscs need escapes, do not you agree?. It also happens to all the time, but in general your approach seems to be the best because avoids complicated regexes.

Comment: @user2571881 - force of habit but you are right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I am looking to only delete comments which include the `@ngdoc` tag in the second line, how would you go about doing that?

Comment: Nevermind, at this point this works great for me. Accepting this answer as it seems to be better practice.

Comment: @fstylermiller - if you know for certain that the `@ngdoc` can only occur in a comment you like to remove and only occur once, you could use `:g/@ngdoc/-1,/\*\/$/d_`. This searches for the lines containing `@ngdoc` and sets the range from the previous line (-1) to the end of the comment (*/).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you have `\{-}` followed by `*` which are the multis referenced in the error message. Quote the `*`:

```
%s/\/\*\*\n \* @ngdoc\_.\{-}\*\/\n//g
```

Comment: I see what you did, but I am still getting the same error. Could it be with the  `**` part?

Comment: Yes, I missed those.

Comment: Thanks! I am not getting the errors any more, but it's not finding the pattern. Something that I can resolve on my own.

Comment: The issue is probably because `.` is not multiline. I changed the pattern to use the multiline `.`.

Comment: It is still not finding it. I also tried using that pattern [here](http://regexr.com/) to no avail.

Comment: Yeah, there are no online testers that support VIM's unique regex syntax.

Comment: I missed another `*`. Better, I think.

Comment: I should mention that this also correctly answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Using embedded newlines in the pattern is the wrong approach.  You should instead use an address range.  Something like:

```
sed '\@^/\*\*$@,\@^\*/$@d' file
```

This will delete all lines starting from one that matches `/**` anchored at column 1 to the line matching `*/` anchored at column 1.  If your comments are well behaved (eg, no trailing space after `/**`), this should do what you want.

Comment: You forgot the requirement for `@ngdoc` at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, I'm running a windows machine. I wish I wasn't!

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `gc` to be careful when deleting

```
%s/\v\/\*\*\n\s\*\s\@ngdoc\n((\s*\n)?(\s\*.*\n)?){-}\s?\*\///gc
```

Match comments like

```
/**
 * @ngdoc

 *  ... comment body (delete me, too!)

 *
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

My approached consists of using a macro:

```
qa/\/\*\*<enter><shift-v>/\*\/<enter>d

qa ........ starts recording macro "a"
/\/\*\* ... searches for the comment beginning
<Enter> ... use Ctrl-v Enter
V ......... starts visual block (until...)
/\*\/ ..... end of your comment
<Enter> ... Ctrl-v Enter agai
d ......... it will delete selected area
```

In order to isert   etc presse  followed by the keyword you want.